# In am getting error while compiling code like this 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build web Scraper using BeautifulSoup , but when i'm compiling the code it gives `find_all method has no attributes`. Here is the code :

```
page = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/images/search")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all('a'))

week = soup.find(id='b_results')
print(week.find_all('li'))
```

Comment: This is a runtime error, not a compiler error, just FYI. If you're trying to scrape bing, very likely [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because there isn't anything with the id `b_results`, so nothing is assigned to week, so when you try to find all in nothing it errors out.